# Is this differential equation solved properly?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have following differential equation for the speed of a particle:
$g=\dfrac{3\alpha}{\alpha t + R_0}v + \overset{.}{v}$

Is my approach right?
$\int (g-\dfrac{3\alpha}{\alpha t + R_0}v)dt = \int dv$

$gt-ln(|\alpha t + R_0|)\cdot 3v=v$

$v=\frac{gt}{1+3ln(|\alpha t + R_0|)}$

Or do I have to care for the dependence of v on t, too, considering the integral in the second line? :)

Comment: No. It is not correct. Your velocity is a function of t and cannot be taken as a constant.

Comment: Thank you:) Do you have any hints on how to approach it?

Answer (score 3):

Use integration factor
$$\exp\bigg[\int_{t_0}^t \frac{3\alpha}{\alpha t + R_0}dt\bigg]=\exp\bigg[3\ln(t+\frac{R_0}{\alpha})|_{t_0}^t\bigg]$$
$$=\exp\bigg[3\ln(t+\frac{R_0}{\alpha})-3\ln(t_0+\frac{R_0}{\alpha})\bigg]$$
$$=(t_0+\frac{R_0}{\alpha})^{-3}(t+\frac{R_0}{\alpha})^3$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}\bigg[v(t_0+\frac{R_0}{\alpha})^{-3}(t+\frac{R_0}{\alpha})^3\bigg]=(t_0+\frac{R_0}{\alpha})^{-3}(t+\frac{R_0}{\alpha})^3g$$
$$v\frac{(t+R_0/\alpha)^3}{(t_0+R_0/\alpha)^3}=\frac{g}{(t_0+R_0/\alpha)^3}\int(t+R_0/\alpha)^3dt$$
$$v(t+R_0/\alpha)^3=g\frac{(t+R_0/\alpha)^4}{4}+C$$
$$v=\frac{g}{4}(t+R_0/\alpha)+C(t+R_0/\alpha)^{-3}$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that the right hand side of the equation looks like something you'd get if you apply the product rule for derivatives. We just have to find the right thing to multiply through by in order to get that form.

In general if we have something of the form:

$$\eta = f(t) \frac{dv}{dt} + v$$

We can multiply through by $$e^{\int f(t)dt}$$

And we'll have:

$$\eta \,e^{\int f(t)dt} = \frac{d}{dt}\left(v\,e^{\int f(t)dt}\right)$$ Note that we can ignore the extra constant we get from the indefinite integral because it just leads to multiplying the whole equation through by a (non-zero) constant.

In this case $$f = \frac{3\alpha}{\alpha t + r_0}$$

So:

$$\int f(t)dt = 3\log(\alpha t + R_0) = \log((\alpha t + R_0)^3)$$

So:

$$e^{\int f(t)dt} = (\alpha t + R_0)^3$$

Therefore your equation is:

$$g(\alpha t + R_0)^3 = \frac{d}{dt}\left(v(\alpha t + R_0)^3\right)$$

Can you solve it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite as

$$v'(\alpha t+R)+3\alpha v=g(\alpha t+R).$$

On the left, you nearly have the derivative of the product $v(\alpha t+R)$, but for the factor $3$. This is dealt with by increasing the power of $(\alpha t+R)$:

$$v'(\alpha t+R)^3+3\alpha(\alpha t+R)^2v=(v(\alpha t+R)^3)'=g(\alpha t+R)^3.$$

Then by integration

$$v(\alpha t+R)^3=\frac g{4\alpha}(\alpha t+R)^4+C.$$